# Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty в состоянии MySQL. Что это?

Tags: mysql

Кто подскажет, что это такое и как от этого избавиться?

В гугле ничего не нашёл, а в их документации всё коротко и неясно:

> > The number of pages currently dirty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грязные страницы (другими словами, страницы, считанные в буфер данных, но не подвергшиеся изменениям) возникают в транзакциях.
Часто такое бывает при фейлах в транзакциях.
Если Вам эти данные ни к чему ( вы не будете восстанавливать транзакции и т.п.) - очистите таблицу.
Можете почитать тут, если очень интересно:

https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=b_BXc2c73PYC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B+sql&source=bl&ots=l4jyUKFSzT&sig=oNTpEaboQgeKbm_M27-_dno6uVs&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=TwrBVOjFPIPqUtSrgdAJ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B%20sql&f=false

Comment: @Влад Дяченко, они никак не влияют на производительность?

Comment: Ну сам понимаешь, пока их на 3kb - ничего не будет. А вот если их будет на 100gb - тут уже будут проблемы)